# Content-Type not being added to Header - Artillery.io

Tags: forms, content-type, artillery

I am trying to create a scenario to curity to get a access token. From my debugging it looks like that the `Content-Type` is not working

```
scenarios:
  - flow:
      - log: "getting token"
      - post:
          url: "/....."
          headers:
            Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          form:
            grant_type: "password"
            response_type: "token"
            username: "Username"
            password: "password1234"
            client_id: "api"
            client_sercret: "clientsecret123"
          expect:
            - statusCode: 200
```

If i change `form` to `json` for exmaple then I can see the body added to the request. I think the Content-Type is not being recognised or the `form` type is not working as expected

the request lkooks like this:

```
  "url": "https://.......com",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "user-agent": "Artillery (https://artillery.io)",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

The body is not included

Comment: Worth noting that this requets works in POSTMAN